# MYSQL which version of update is faster

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm coding queries for a MYSQL database i created. I have a very large amount of rows and i'm asking myself which version of update is faster.

Is faster:

a) Version with WERE

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2
SET t1.c1 = 'something'
WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

or

b) Version without WERE

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN table t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
SET t1.c1 = 'something'
```

?

The question could be also: is it better to specify the "CONDITION" in the JOIN of two tables or in the WERE statement in an update in MYSQL to get faster performance?

Comment: It doesn't matter, they are equivalent. PS: "I have a very large amount of rows" --- how about learning how to use `EXPLAIN` then?

Comment: You will gain more Update-speed by adding proper indices - eg. on `t2.c1`

Comment: @Benni Can you give me an example?

Comment: ALTER TABLE t2 ADD INDEX myINDEX (c1)